# Group div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="productName">Red hoodie</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="productName">Blue hoodie</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="productName">Green hoodie</div>
</div>
```

and these product divs are more (like 50 or something).
Is there any way to group them (2 product divs in one row div) with javascript or jquery, for example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="productName">Red hoodie</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="productName">Blue hoodie</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="productName">Green hoodie</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: First, let me ask why you want this? Can't we just focus on rendering the results the way you want?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/  with subsets of the elements

Comment: @Phiter no i haven't

Comment: @ScottMarcus because I want to add banner with products that have discount after 4 rows

Comment: @KristersDzintars Ok, so to do that does not require changing the structure of the HTML. We simply need to count down to the 4th row and insert the banner.

Answer (score -1):

Not to waste your time or anything, but you'll regret making the decision of 'grouping' your divs somewhere down the line. Bad idea

Comment: This isn’t an answer, but a comment on the question.